# How to add an object with an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating these two methods in which in the first I validate the existence of a vehicle from its name. In the second, it is intended to add a new vehicle, validating first, if there is a vehicle with a certain name, to avoid duplication of results. However, I always get the error described.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Only the `preco_base` attribute is mutable

```
def exists_viatura(self, nome):
    for v in self.gestor:
        if v.nome == nome:
            return True
        else:
            print("Não existe nenhuma viatura")

def add_viatura(self, new_v):
    for v in self.gestor:
        new_v = Viatura(new_v.nome, new_v.modelo, new_v.tipo_electrica, new_v.preco_base)
        if g.exists_viatura(new_v.nome):
            print("Já existe uma viatura com esse nome")
    self.gestor.append(new_v)
```

I am obtainin the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/sandr/PycharmProjects/projecto/Classes_Projecto.py", line 189, in add_viatura
    new_v = Viatura(new_v.nome, new_v.modelo, new_v.tipo_electrica, new_v.preco_base)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nome'
```

The classes are:

```
class Viatura:

    def __init__(self, nome, modelo, tipo_electrica, preco_base):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__modelo = modelo
        self.__tipo_electrica = tipo_electrica #Como saber se uma bicicleta é eléctrica ou não?
        self.preco_base = preco_base

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    @property
    def modelo(self):
        return self.__modelo

    @property
    def tipo_electrica(self):
        return self.__tipo_electrica

class Gestor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gestor = []
```

Comment: Sounds like you're calling `add_viatura` with a `str` argument.

Comment: Where did `new_v` come from? Is it already a Viatura object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if new_v isn't actually a Viatura object (since you are trying to add it, using a string), then you should pass the rest of attributes to add_viatura.

```py
def exists_viatura(self, nome):
    for v in self.gestor:
        if v.nome == nome:
            return True
    print("Não existe nenhuma viatura")
    return False

def add_viatura(self, nome, modelo, tipo_electrica, preco_base):
        if g.exists_viatura(nome):
            print("Já existe uma viatura com esse nome")
        else:
            new_v = Viatura(nome, modelo, tipo_electrica, preco_base)
            self.gestor.append(new_v)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to create an object inside the method add_viatura and evaluate these object?

Comment: You don't need to create an object to check if the Ventura object exists, all you need (according to your code) is the `nome` to check against all names of Ventura objects. It seems that you are supplying the `nome` only (an str) to add_ventura, which isn't enough to create a new Ventura object.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, don't know what class this resides in;  `g`?  You called it `g.exists_viatura()`?

```
def exists_viatura( self, nome ):
    for v in self .gestor:
        if v .nome == nome:
            return True
    print("Não existe nenhuma viatura")
    return False


def add_viatura( self, new_v ):
        if g.exists_viatura( new_v.nome ):
            print("Já existe uma viatura com esse nome")
        else:
            car = Viatura( new_v.nome, new_v.modelo, new_v.tipo_electrica, new_v.preco_base )
            self .gestor .append( car )
```

Comment: I have to create a method add_viatura in class Gestor. It adds a new object Viatura if it has a differen name from other Viaturas.